# sin^2 (n) / n series when sin is defined on complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I encountered a problem that I can't figure out. I need to see whether the following series converges or diverges: $\frac{\sin^2(n)}{n}$, with n from 1 to infinity. The problem is that sin is defined on complex numbers, so this time sin can take values outside the interval $[-1,1]$. How do you solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(n)}n$$

Comment: Did you mean $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(n)}n$$

Comment: yes, that's the series I need

Comment: How is $\sin$ being defined on complex numbers relevant here since you're summing over $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: When you define the sine function over the complex numbers, $\sin z$ has the usual value when $z$ happens to be a real number. Here, $n = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ are real values.

Comment: That's what I can't figure out, I've been told I need to use the complex form of sin, but I don't see for what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that

$$\sin^2(n)=\frac{1-\cos(2n)}2$$

And it's easy to use $\cos(2n)=\Re(e^{2in})$ to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin^2(n)}n=\frac12\Re\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac{e^{2in}}n\right)\right]$$

The right most part of the sum converges by the Dirichlet test while the first part diverges by the p-series, hence, your series diverges.

Comment: How do you apply Dirichlet on e^(2in)/n ? I'm sorry if I'm asking something simple.

Comment: Note that $\sum e^{2in}$ is bounded and $1/n\to0$.

Comment: Why is e^2in bounded? Isn't its limit infinite? I tried writing it as a geometric progression and got to the same conclusion.

Comment: It's merely a geometric series.  Solve the geometric series and show that it is bounded.

Comment: I arrived at e^(2i) * (e^(2in) - 1) / (e^(2i) - 1) and I don't know how to continue. I tried writing e^2in as cos n + i cos n, but I didn't arrive to anything.

Comment: * i sin n, sorry for the typo

Comment: @Jay_Peters Note that $$|e^{2in}-1|\le|e^{2in}|+|-1|=2$$Thus, it is bounded...

Comment: Ah, I understand! Thank you very much for helping me out and sorry for asking so many questions!

Comment: No problem! :-)